# example.herokuapp.com redirection to https://example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have a rails app deployed on heroku, domain by google and DNS by cloudflare. I would like to redirect all the requests that come to `example.herokuapp.com` to `example.com`. I can't set this on cloudflare, since if I use a page rule that would send the traffic from `example.herokuapp.com` to `example.com` then cloudflare raises this error: `ERROR Your URL should reference the domain 'example.com' in some way.`

I also checked on heroku, but I don't really get what I should do:

"Your app’s Heroku Domain will always remain active, even if you’ve set up a custom domain. If you want users to use the custom domain exclusively, your app should send HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently to tell web browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request header field will show which domain the user is trying to access; send a redirect if that field is example.herokuapp.com."

What is the preferred way to redirect the traffic to the `https://example.com`?

UPDATE

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{.*}, "https://example.com$&", 
  :if => Proc.new { |rack_env| rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'example.com' }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) for this.

First add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-rewrite'
```

Then run `bundle install`.

Now add the following to your `config.ru` file:

```
require 'rack-rewrite'

use Rack::Rewrite do
  r301 %r{.*}, "https://example.com$&", :if => Proc.new {|rack_env|
    rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'example.com'
  }
end
```

If the request is not for `example.com` then it will do a 301 redirect to `https://example.com`

Comment: infused, I checked out the documentation, but it's not exactly clear. I'm using rails 4.2.4, and the docs recommend a bit different code. Could you take a look at my updated question where I have the code that I'm planning to use based on the docs? Could you also tell me if this code will break dev env if I have it without defining the environment.